# Accessing non-static member in c# Lazy *without* using default constructor

Tags: c#, static, lazy-loading

I want to add a `Lazy` to my class. To access non-static members inside the initialization method of the `Lazy`, the best-practice method (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14029443/10406502) is to define the `Lazy` inside the default constructor. This is not possible in my project, because it's a partial class and the default constructor is already defined by some auto-generated code (Entity Framework).

Is there a way to use `Lazy` accessing non-static class members *without* implementing it in the default constructor?

Comment: `private Lazy<int> lazyGetSum = new Lazy<int>(new Func<int>(() => X + Y));`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Doesn't work, because you can't access non-static members inside `Func<int>` (in your example).

Comment: What non-static members?

Comment: @RobertHarvey See the question linked in the OP. That does e.g. `new Lazy<int>(() => X + Y)` where `X` and `Y` are instance members.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I need to access `this` inside the `Lazy`: `DatabaseEntities db = (DatabaseEntities)EntityContextExtensioncs.GetDbContextFromEntity(this); return db.MyTable.ToHashSet();`

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031936

Comment: @RobertHarvey That throws me a design-time CS0759: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0759

Comment: You'll have to do a bit of poking around on the Internet, but I'm pretty sure this is the right approach.  See also https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/31793997

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you very much! I've posted an answer based on your hints.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Robert Harvey, I found the following solution: First, you have to add some stuff to your data model template `MyModeName.tt`, which you can find under the `MyModelName.edmx` in your project. I added a new partial method `private partial void OnConstructorCompletion();` and called it at the end of the constructor. I modified the document as follows (lines 27-67):

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
{
    private partial void OnConstructorCompletion();

<#
    var propertiesWithDefaultValues = typeMapper.GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(entity);
    var collectionNavigationProperties = typeMapper.GetCollectionNavigationProperties(entity);
    var complexProperties = typeMapper.GetComplexProperties(entity);

    if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || collectionNavigationProperties.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public <#=code.Escape(entity)#>()
    {
<#
        foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#> = <#=typeMapper.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
        }

        foreach (var navigationProperty in collectionNavigationProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
<#
        }

        foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(complexProperty)#> = new <#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
        }
#>

        OnConstructorCompletion();
    }
```

Next, I implemented the method where required inside of my entity class:

```cs
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public Lazy<ICollection<MyNavigationEntity>> NavigationProperty;

    private partial void OnConstructorCompletion()
    {
        NavigationProperty= new Lazy<ICollection<MyNavigationEntity>>(() =>
        {
            DatabaseEntities db = (DatabaseEntities)EntityContextExtensions.GetDbContextFromEntity(this);

            return db.MyNavigationEntity
                .Where(ne => ne.ID == this.ID_MyNavigationEntity)
                .ToHashSet();
        });
    }
}
```